# SOAP UI tool not manintaing Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soapui

I am testing .net Web service on SOAPUI tool.

I found that SOAP UI not maintaining Asp.Net Session.

Further if I create a new client that using .Net Web service than session is maintained.

What wrongs here?

Answer (score 0):

Your client need to support cookies in order to provide session identifier. 
I think you can do that by simple creating a new container like this:

```
myclient.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
```

Look at this articles for more details:

[Managing shared cookies in WCF](http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/)

HOW TO: [Use CookieContainer to Maintain a State in Web Services When You Use Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816637)

This forum thread may be hellpfull
http://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13170

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if i need to describe about SOAP UI that this tool is a stand alone application for testing Services only, if i am not wrong above object of coding is not supported in SOAP UI, if supported than please define it with example